# R detect zeroes in ts object

Tags: r, time-series

Simple question : in R, what's the best way to detect if there is a zero somewhere in a time series (ts class)? I run X13 (seasonal package) on hundreds of time series and I would like to identify those who contain zero values (since multiplicative models don't work when they encounter a zero). If I could detect those series, I could use a IF-THEN-ELSE statement with proper specs for the X13.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace or delete them:

```r
ts <- ts(0:10)

## Deleting
ts[ts != 0]
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

## Replacing
replace(ts, ts==0, 1)
#> Time Series:
#> Start = 1 
#> End = 11 
#> Frequency = 1 
#>  [1]  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

## Detecting
any(ts == 0)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't want to replace them, I just want to know if they are there. If a series contains a (or several) zero somewhere, I'll seasonally adjust it using an additive model rather than a multiplicative one. I only want to discriminate the series that contains zeroes vs the series that don't have any.

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can detect zeros by any(ts == 0)